# How to activate application and focus a widget on gtk/ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gtk

On recent versions of Ubunutu with the Unity desktop manager, how is it possible to activate your running application and bring it to the foreground programmatically?

That is to say, suppose  you had a timer in your graphical application set to 3 minutes. Is there a way to activate your application, bring it to the foreground, and set focus to it when the timer expires?

I've searched around for APIs to help with this.

gtk_window_present() isn't actually making my application the active application. When I call it the active application remains unchanged.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ptomato, in my real world case my application needs to popup a screen based on a global hotkey. When the hotkey is pressed my application takes a screenshot and then allows the user to crop their selection and save it to a url. So yes, I need to popup my background window and activate it programatically.

The solution I found was in the wmctrl source code. By implementing part of the NetWM messaging specification, I can commincate with the window manager (Compiz, KWin, Metacity) and not the toolkit, asking it to activate my program.

The specific message I needed was _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW along with the XID of my window. When this event is sent (XSendEvent) to the root window, any window manager which implements NetWM messaging will bring the windows I ask to the foreground and give it input focus. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, but I think you should take a different approach. Programmatically bringing an application to the foreground is a security risk. For example, the user could be just about to type their password into their online banking login page when your window jumps to the foreground and grabs the keyboard focus.

This has actually happened to me — luckily not with an online banking password, though — and since then I usually just discontinue use of applications that pop to the front, if I can.

Instead, I think you should use [`g_application_send_notification()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GApplication.html#g-application-send-notification) to notify the user that the operation has finished. In most desktops, clicking on the notification will bring the window to the foreground, so you'll achieve essentially the same effect without taking the user by surprise.